# Android set contact to favorite programmatically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts, android-contacts

Can any one told me if I have a list of contact and read them in my application and I want to set contact to favorite from my application directly, so that when I open my phone contact again I will be able to find contact in the favorite list of android phone.

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you must add permission to your application to be able to write to the contact content provider.
`android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`

After that you need to update the value for the STARRED field.

`ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
v.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED,1);
getContentResolver().update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, v, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1+"=?", new String[]{putThePhoneNumberHere+""});`

Answer (score 3):

You need to update value STARRED in contacts database from 0 to 1.

Something like:

```
values.put(Contacts.STARRED, 1);

getContentResolver().update(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "= ?", strNamevalue);
```

This is a sql query:

```
UPDATE %Contacts.CONTENT_URI% SET STARRED = 1 WHERE %Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME% = %strNamevalue%
```

*Values in %% should be replaced by valid table name and where clause params*

Hope it helps