# Android adding contact to favorites programmatically - starred column does not exists

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I've been trying to add some contacts to favorites programmatically and this is done by update the STARRED value from 0 to 1 of that particular contact but whenever i execute the query it throws an `SQLite exception` letting my know that the STARRED column does not exist.

[image]

```
contactsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED, 1);
        getActivity().getContentResolver()
        .update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
            contentValues, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+ " = 'Joe Luis'", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `STARRED` field is a part of the `Contacts` table, not the `Data` not `Phone` tables.
You can access Phone.STARRED because all queries on the Data tables support implicit joins with some fields from the Contacts table, including STARRED.

This is the correct code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Contacts.STARRED, 1);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
        contentValues, 
        Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+ " = 'Joe Luis'", null);
};
```

However please note that modifying contacts based on non-unique items like the display name is a really bad practice, as you might have more then one contact with the same name on the device, or you may empty DISPLAY_NAMEs that will really cause damage to many contacts.

Instead you should always use a unique field - Contacts._ID - to use as the selection of your updates, like so:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long contactId = getContactIdFromPosition(position); // you need to implement this!

    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Contacts.STARRED, 1);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
        contentValues, Contacts._ID + "=" + contactId, null);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, haha and good point on using a different field instead of a contact name, I was using it just for testing purpose:), I did what you recommended and it worked perfectly, thank you God bless you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are updating a different location of the contacts

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" = 'Joe Luis'", null);
```

You should point to the Contacts data field. In this case `ContactsContract.Contacts.Data` not `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds`

Please use this method [Set Contact to favorite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932129/android-set-contact-to-favorite-programmatically/23932337#answer-23932337)